# Magento 2: Which pages are cached via FPC?

Tags: magento2, cache, full-page-cache

I'm having issues with cache and I would like to know which pages are natively cached and uncached by Magento 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Cacheable

There is a list of default pages which are cacheable:

- Home page
- Category page
- Products list page
- Product page
- CMS page

---

## Uncacheable

And there is a list of pages defined as uncacheable:

- Cart page
- Checkout page
- All pages of customer account

[Reference here](https://mirasvit.com/blog/common-issues-and-few-hacks-with-magento-2-full-page-cache.html)